# Sibling directives sharing scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm running into an issue where, through a directive, I am trying to set a property on the scope of a controller. The issue is that, for some reason, the scope on the directive seems to be isolating itself, but only in this instance. It works fine in other places of the application. So when I attempt to use `$scope.files` in my controller, it's coming back as undefined.

Controller:

```
app.controller('newProjectModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, $location, account, $http){

  $scope.account = account.data;

  $scope.project = {
    name: '',
    client: '',
    users: [],
    image: '/assets/images/add-project-photo.jpg'
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  $scope.updateImage = function(item){
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.readAsDataURL($scope.files.item(0));

    filereader.onload = function(event){
      $scope.project.image = event.target.result;
    }
  }

  $scope.submit = function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $scope.files.item(0));

    $http.post($scope.api_url + '/Project', $scope.project)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $modalInstance.close();
        $location.path('/project/' + data.id);
    });
  };
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function($parse){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<input type="file" name="file" multiple style="height:100%;width:100%;display:inline-block;opacity:0.0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0" />',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var onFileChange = $parse(attrs.fileUpload);
            var file = element.children('input');

            file.on('change', function(){
                scope.files = file[0].files;
                onFileChange(scope);
            })

        }
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="row fieldset not" id="photo">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <h2 class="tight">Add project photo</h2>
    <div class="add-project-photo" file-upload="updateImage()" style="background-image: url({{project.image}})"></div>
    <span class="note">300px <i>by</i> 120px</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The template is only partial... the file itself is rather large

Edit: I should mention that the modal is being built using UI-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not transcluding anything, you can remove `transclude: true` from your `fileUpload` directive.  You can also set `scope: false` to tell the directive to use parent (controller) scope.

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function($parse){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        template: '<input type="file" name="file" multiple style="height:100%;width:100%;display:inline-block;opacity:0.0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0" />',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var onFileChange = $parse(attrs.fileUpload);
            var file = element.children('input');

            file.on('change', function(){
                scope.files = file[0].files;
                onFileChange(scope);
            })

        }
    }
});
```